# Magento 2 how to set cron config path value

Tags: magento2

I am working magento 2 extension development. i am now able to set cron config path. I have used following code but it is not working.

i have created `crontab.xml` and put following code into this xml but this is not working.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="test_cron" instance="MyCompany\Test\Cron\Test" method="execute">            
            <config_path>mycompany/test/cron_daily</config_path>            
        </job>        
    </group>
</config>
```

Please let me know how can i set cron config path value?

Answer (score 1):

It is right code which I have described above for cron tab.

I think when cron is running it will insert our cron entry into cron table instantly but when we use`<config_path>`then it will not insert instantly so I have checked with set **`* * * * *`** value and it is working fine.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?